# from . import _iterative ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, dll, scipy

I am trying to clone the `cakechat` repository from https://github.com/lukalabs/cakechat
I created a Python virtual `env` with python 3.6.8.
I ran `pip install -r requirements.txt -r requirements-local.txt` to install the requirements.
But every time I run Python `tools/fetch.py` I get this error:

```
from . import _iterative
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have tried everything from resinstalling the libraries to using different versions altogether. nothing works for me.

Comment: Hi — Download `msvcp71.dll` and `msvcr71.dll` from the web. Save them to your `C:\Windows\System32` folder. This should ideally fix your issue.

Comment: It is also worth noting that Python 3.6 reached upstream end-of-life on December 23rd, 2021 and hence most modules might not work. The project is unmaintained hence there are high chances of the project being dysfunctional.